# Create dynamic optional parameter for inferred generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object that is shaped like this:

```
{
  first: (state: S, payload: boolean) => { payload: boolean, type: string },
  second: (state: S) => { payload: undefined, type: string },
}
```

And I'm generating an object where the `state` property is taken out. So it looks like this:

```
{
  first: (payload: boolean) => { payload: boolean, type: string },
  second: () => { payload: undefined, type: string },
}
```

The returned object is typed like this:

```
{ [K in keyof T]: { (payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1]): { payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1]; type: K; }; name: K; } }
```

Where `Parameters<T[K]>[1]` can clearly be `undefined` (as in the `second` case above).

This *mostly* works fine. I get the correct type inference of the function names, the parameters, and the return types, EXCEPT if the `payload` is undefined. It still wants me to specify it. For example:

```
first(true); // works, no errors
first('true'); // fails because it's the wrong type. Excellent

second(undefined) // works, no errors
second(); // errors
```

The error is:

```
(property) second: (payload: undefined) => {
    payload: undefined;
    type: "second";
}
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. [ts(2554)]
```

So the question is how can I make this optional, but only when the `payload` is not provided? If I add `(payload?: Parameters<T[K]>[1])` in the return type then *all* the functions have this property as optional, and if I add `(payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1] | undefined)` - I still get the same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to create a conditional function declaration in the return type, like this:

```
{ [K in keyof T]: Parameters<T[K]>[1] extends undefined ?
  { (): { payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1]; type: K; }; name: K; } :
  { (payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1]): { payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1]; type: K; }; name: K; }
}
```